# Custom border rounding value for input outline

Tags: css, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui, tailwind-elements

I'm using framework Tailwind-Elements 1.1.0.

I want to make the input outline field with more rounded borders. I found out from the documentation that the default rounded value for input outline is 0.25rem (4px). I want to set rounded to 0.75rem (12px).
I managed to set the rounded value for input outline to 0.75rem, but for some reason the rounding of the left border does not match the right one, although the style is set absolutely correctly.

In the screenshots, you can see that the rounding of the left border is different from the right border. I want the rounding of the left and right border to be equal to 0.75rem (12px). How to fix it?
[image]
[image]
[image]

My CSS code:

```
[data-te-input-notch-trailing-ref] {
    @apply !rounded-r-2xl
}
[data-te-input-notch-leading-ref] {
    @apply !rounded-l-2xl
}
```

How to fix it?